Sets of names/symbols.
If I were to write down a set S containing the words for the fruits apple, cherry and banana in the English language in lower case, I would write something like
S =  {apple, cherry, banana}. But that makes me think that it is not possible to write down a set of fruits apple, cherry and banana.
Then aren't 1, 2, 3 etc. just symbols for numbers and numbers are abstract, so is it even possible to write down any set. Is it just convention to consider  what the words/symbols represent rather than thinking of them as sets of words/symbols? How is the distinction made between the two?

It's not an exact answer, but you may be interested in Tarski's theory of truth: "P" is true if, and only if, P is true.

Your second paragraph seems more like a question of semiotics than mathematics, but as for your first paragraph, what do you think about { , ,  }?

I just want to know how the sets of symbols and sets of what the symbols represent are distinguishable in writing. Your example also uses symbols, someone can argue that it is not the set of those three fruits but rather a set containing a specific pictorial representation of them.

Writing is always symbols.

Mathematics is based on axioms. So what is the fundamental axiomatic theory of sets? Zermelo-Fraenkel (ZF) set theory of course.
What that theory tells us is that at least the empty set $\emptyset$ exists. In a very practical sense: the theory says it exists. And then based on various axioms we build natural numbers out of it:
$$0:=\emptyset$$
$$1:=\{\emptyset\}$$
$$2:=\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$$
etc. In general the successor of natural number $n$ is defined as $n\cup\{n\}$. And then we construct other sets in similar fashion, based on unions, intersections, Cartesian products, etc.
So indeed, sets are abstract thing, more or less labels. Entire mathematics is an abstract thing. There is no set of fruits, of cars, or animals, or whatever. We often use this term to mean that some physical phenomena can be modeled through abstract mathematical constructs. And then we can deduce various properties of it based solely on this abstract representation.
How well it corresponds to reality is a different question though. Depending on what you are studying, modeling say apple, cherry and banana as a set might be incorrect (e.g. quantum phenomena). But it often is good enough.

Is it just convention to consider what the words/symbols represent rather than thinking of them as sets of words/symbols?

Mathematical theories don't care about what those symbols actually mean. Diving deeper you may ask what a symbol is? It doesn't matter. From mathematical perspective we only care about theories, meaning what properties those beings have.
So, back to ZF: what the empty set really is? It doesn't matter. It might be the set of apple, cherry and banana, as long as every other symbol (e.g. $\in$) is defined in such way that it satisfies ZF axioms. And, indeed it can be defined in a way that it works.
With this approach mathematical theories can be reused in various different contexts, without the need of understanding the nature of the underlying things.

I don't know whether this answers your question, but it seems an important point to make:
In (material) set theory, in order to make sense of the set $\{\mathrm{apple}, \mathrm{cherry}, \mathrm{banana}\}$, you would have to arbitrarily choose (distinct) sets to represent $\mathrm{apple}$, $\mathrm{cherry}$ and $\mathrm{banana}$.
In type theory, you could simply define $S$ as an inductive type with three constructors $\mathrm{apple}$, $\mathrm{cherry}$ and $\mathrm{banana}$. In this sense, type theory is a more structural foundation of mathematics: it doesn't matter what an element of $S$ is, only that there are three of them and we have a distinct name for each. Anything meaningful that you can prove about $S$ would also be true for any other 3-element set (provided that you translate the names accordingly), whereas the set-theoretic encoding would force you to pick answers to absurd questions like $\mathrm{apple} \in \mathrm{banana}$.
Similarly, natural numbers in set theory have to be represented using a more or less clever encoding, whereas in type theory the type of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ is defined as having a constructor $0 : \mathbb{N}$ and a constructor $S : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$.
